# Add http://xxx.xx/ to a string using python

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

How can I add "http://test.url/" to the result `link.get('href')` below, but only if it doesn't contain "http"

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "http://www.salatomatic.com/c/Sydney+168"
content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
  print link.get('href')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    currenturl =  link.get('href')
    if not currenturl.startswith("http"):
        currenturl = "http://test.url/" + currenturl
    print currenturl
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`urlparse.urljoin`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http://example.com/', '/a/b')
'http://example.com/a/b'
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http://example.com/', 'http://www.example.com/a/b')
'http://www.example.com/a/b'
```

In Python 3.x, use [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin):

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin('http://example.com/', '/a/b')
'http://example.com/a/b'
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin('http://example.com/', 'http://www.example.com/a/b')
'http://www.example.com/a/b'
```

---

**Complete example**

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse

url1 = "http://www.salatomatic.com/c/Sydney+168"
content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print urlparse.urljoin(url1, link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use `urljoin`

```
>>> from urlparse import urljoin
>>> urljoin('http://test.url/', '/relative/path')
'http://test.url/relative/path'
```

In your example you only need to do this when you find a relative url.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "http://www.salatomatic.com/c/Sydney+168"
content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
   get = link.get('href')
   if get.startswith('http'):
      print get
```

In the spirit of BeautifulSoup, this works well with your original code.

If what you want is to preface the non-`http` sites with a `http://test.url/` then you need to do this:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
   get = link.get('href')
   if not get.startswith('http'):
      print 'http://test.url/'+get
```

You're set either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
This works:

    url = "http://test.url/" 

    link_list = [link['href'] for link in soup.findAll('a')]

    result_list = [url+i if 'http' not in i else i for i in link_list]

    for link in result_link:
        print link
```